# Iterator query C++

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

So I am working on a simple example which uses iterators. Here is a list of pair of ints and contains 2 elements initially.
{1,1} -> {2,2}
now I run the code below, so initially the it points to {2,2} so my understanding was that the iterator pointing to {2,2} is now copied in it and it will remain same but when I do values.pop_back() in the next line it automatically points to {1,1} now . How is this possible

can any one help me understand this behaviour ?

```
list<pair<int, int>>::reverse_iterator it = values.rbegin();
      values.pop_back();
      auto pos = locator.find( it->first);
      if( pos != locator.end())
      {
          locator.erase( pos);

      }
```

Comment: `pop_back()` has no bearing on the fact that you declared a reverse iterator. You did, however, invalidate `it` when you popped, so anything after is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: OK it means that pop_back() frees the memory after removing the element causing (it) is invalidated.

Comment: Per [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/pop_back): "*References and iterators to the erased element are invalidated.*"  You have an iterator referring to the element that is being popped.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't think it's that simple. `it` is a `reverse_iterator`, wrapping `it.base()` that is `values.end()`. The `end()` iterator should still be valid after `pop_back()`. So I believe `it` is still a valid reverse iterator referring to `*std::prev(values.end())`, that is, whatever element happens to be last in `values`.

Answer (score 0):

Reverse iterators are weird this way. A reverse iterator wraps a "real" iterator, accessible as `it.base()`. This "real" iterator is one element behind, pointing to the element **following** the one that the reverse iterator appears to refer to. That is, `&*it == &*std::prev(it.base())`. This is necessary because in a container, there's a valid one-past-the-last iterator, but there isn't a valid one-before-first iterator for `rend()` to wrap.

In your example, after `it = values.rbegin();`, you have `it.base() == values.end()`. Accessing `it` actually accesses `std::prev(values.end())`, or in other words, `values.back()` - whatever element happens to be last currently.

In `std::list`, `pop_back()` invalidates iterators to the element being removed, but not any others - in particular, `values.end()` is still valid, and so `it` is still valid and still refers to `values.back()` - the last element after the removal.

Comment: "*you have `it.base() == values.end()`*" - not according to [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator): "*Reverse iterator stores an iterator to **the next element** than the one it actually refers to.*" Which means `rbegin()` returns a `reverse_iterator` that has an iterator to the element **before** `end()`, which is the element being popped. See the diagram on that page.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't see the contradiction. `rbegin()` returns a reverse iterator referring to the last element. The iterator it stores then needs to refer to the element after that - but there's no element after that, so that stored iterator is `end()`. The picture in the article you cite makes it clear. You can also test experimentally that indeed, `values.rbegin().base() == values.end()`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Per **[container.requirements.general]** Table 84 — Reversible container requirements, `a.rbegin()` returns `reverse_iterator(end())`